# Responding to Slash Commands

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, discord, discord.js

I created my own class that supports Slash Commands in discord.js. When I use the SlashCommandsHandler#sendReply() function and provide embed as an argument, it is sent without a MessageAttachment. How to fix this?
[Code in command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GcxUf.png)

[Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FrdWq.png)

Expected response:
[Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FrdWq.png) with MessageAttachment

Function code:
[Function code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBFcH.png)

Thanks for help!
(Bot written in Typescript)

Comment: PS. SlashCommandsHandler#createEmbed works properly

Answer (score 0):

Finally I removed slash commands from my bot, in normal commands all works properly